# Using a SVG path as a marker icon in Google Maps causes extreme lag when there are many markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to render markers on a map.

I experience worsening lag in interacting with the map as the number of markers increases (we're talking several hundred to several thousand markers).

This lag occurs when the icon used to render the marker is an SVG path-- either a custom SVG path or one of the built in paths available in the Maps library such as `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE`--

```
const icon = {
  // path: 'M 10, 10 m -7.5, 0 a 7.5,7.5 0 1,0 15,0 a 7.5,7.5 0 1,0 -15,0'
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE
};
```

If I use `url` instead of a `path`, the performance is great and there's no lag. A static SVG works without lag as well

```
const icon = {
  url: 'some-image.png'
  // url: 'some-image.svg'
};
```

`some-image.svg` contains the same path that creates the lag--

```
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path 
    d="M 10, 10 m -7.5, 0 a 7.5,7.5 0 1,0 15,0 a 7.5,7.5 0 1,0 -15,0"
    fill="red" 
    stroke="blue" 
    stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

I see this lag on Chrome (60) and Firefox (58), but not on Edge.

I'd ideally like to be able to use SVG paths to render icons as it will allow fine-grained control over the visuals in a data-dependent manner, as opposed to having pre-rendered static assets.

Does anyone have experience in solving the lag/performance issue?

Thank you.

Here are two snippets. Try panning and zooming to note the difference between the two. (If you get an error while running the snippet, try clicking the 'run' button multiple times. It may take a few moments for the libraries to load)

The first demonstrates using an SVG path for the icon (the built in SymbolPath.CIRCLE)--

```js
function initMap(){
  const mapConfig = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7274929, -73.8519416),
    zoom: 12,
  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapConfig)
  let icon;
  icon = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 3,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    strokeColor: 'gray',
    strokeWeight: 1
  };
    
  jQuery.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/he7q-3hwy.json', data => {
    data.forEach(row => {
      const point = row.the_geom.coordinates;
      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1], point[0]);
      new google.maps.Marker({ position, icon, map, draggable: false });
    });
  });

}
```

```css
    #container {
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEKtLNmzXRdMPn-SKFfu97qMQrfgbqOcU&callback=initMap">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

The second snippet uses a static PNG--

```js
function initMap(){
  const mapConfig = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7274929, -73.8519416),
    zoom: 12,
  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapConfig)
  let icon;
  icon = { url: 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png' };
    
  jQuery.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/he7q-3hwy.json', data => {
    data.forEach(row => {
      const point = row.the_geom.coordinates;
      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1], point[0]);
      new google.maps.Marker({ position, icon, map, draggable: false });
    });
  });

}
```

```css
    #container {
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEKtLNmzXRdMPn-SKFfu97qMQrfgbqOcU&callback=initMap">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your icon is too big.  If I shrink it (scale: 0.1), the performance returns (and I don't see the issue with the "built-in": google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE) .  Any reason you are using such a big icon? See the behavior in all browsers I have on this PC, Chrome 63.0.3239.132, Firefox 57.0.4, IE 11.0.9600.18893.

Comment: @geocodezip thank you for the reply. I don't believe the icon size matters too much. I've scaled it down and see the same issue. I am okay with using google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE anyway. I just wanted to rule out if the built in path had some kind of issue. I've provided two snippets that I hope demonstrates the difference between using a static image vs an SVG path.

Comment: I believe svg path icon are not cache-able, that might explain the delay.

Comment: Hi, did you find an alternative to this, other than building static SVG files?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Ended up using static files to get around the caching issue. I believe it comes down to how the browser handles it. Edge outperforms Chrome/Firefox in this instance.